# MySQL вернула пустой результат (т.е. ноль строк). (Запрос занял 0,0012 сек.)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, openserver

В базу данных не добавляются данные

php код:

```
$login = filter_var(
    trim($_POST['name']),
    FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
);
$email = filter_var(
    trim($_POST['mail']),
    FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
);
$pass = filter_var(
    trim($_POST['pass']),
    FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
);

if (mb_strlen($login) < 5 || mb_strlen($login) > 90) {
    echo "Недопустимая длина поля";
    exit();
} else if (mb_strlen($email) < 6 || mb_strlen($email) > 30) {
    echo "Недопустимая длина почты";
    exit();
} else if (mb_strlen($pass) < 3 || mb_strlen($pass) > 15) {
    echo "Недопустимая длина пароля";
    exit();
}

$mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'train');
$mysql->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `email`, `pass`)
VALUES('$login', '$email', '$pass')");

$mysql->close();
```

Comment: Откуда известно, что результат пустой, если он нигде не запоминается?

Comment: а сколько строк вы ожидаете вернуть от insert запроса?